# How to use automake to link two libs, one dynamically and the other statically?

Tags: build, automake, pkg-config

Suppose I want to link the **foo** application with the **bar** and **baz** libs. Both support pkg-config and provide .pc files. The **bar** lib I want to link **dynamically** and the **baz** library I want to link **statically**. How can I achieve this with **automake**?

My current setup links both of them dinamycally and looks like this:

```
foo_SOURCES = main.c
foo_LDADD = @BAR_LIBS@ @BAZ_LIBS@
foo_CFLAGS = @BAR_CFLAGS@ @BAZ_CFLAGS@
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no (justifiable) reason to not use shared libraries when they are available. automake provides no specific support here; there's is the `-Wl,-Bstatic ${FOO_LIBS} -Wl,-Bdynamic` hack, but it is what it is - a hack, and there is no guarantee it will work at all times.

Comment: Even libraries up to a few kilobytes? Libs that usually are not even packaged by common distributions? Static linking is a feature and can be used to solve problems or to create new ones. Why make it an evil thing?